# How to skip some arabic labels in task environment?

Tags: tasks

I am writing an answer key to a (math) problem set which contains, suppose, 10 problems. To generate a sequence of numbers I am using `task` environment with global settings `\NewTasks[label = {\bf \arabic*.},label-width=4ex]{answers}[\a]`.

For example, suppose the problem number 5, 6, 7 are 'prove that' type problems. It means that I don't need to show their answers in the answer key. So, I want to generate a sequence from 1 to 4 and then from 8 to 10.

I don't know how to skip these three particular numbers. I am using TexShop 4.58.

My code is

```
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\NewTasks[label = {\bf \arabic*.},label-width=4ex]{answers}[\a]
\begin{document}
\begin{answers}(5)
\a (C)
\a (D)
\a (D)
\a (C)
\a (D)
\a (A)
\a (C)
\a (C)
\a (A)
\a (B)
\end{answers}
\end{document}
```

It produces

[image: output]

Please tell me what changes should I do to get desired output?

Thanks

Comment: You know the drill: Please provide a self-contained, compilable example document that sets up your overall document properties. Without it, any answer will require so much guesswork as having little chance of being of value to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `\addtocounter{task}{...}` where you need it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasksEnvironment[label=\arabic*.,label-format=\bfseries,label-width=4ex]{answers}[\a]
  
\begin{document}

\begin{answers}(4)
  \a (A)
  \a (C)
  \a (D) \addtocounter{task}{3}
  \a (C)
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

If you want to directly type in the number you want to step up to: that can be done with a little bit of simple math:

```
\newcommand\gototask[1]{\addtocounter{task}{\numexpr#1-\value{task}\relax}}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasksEnvironment[label=\arabic*.,label-format=\bfseries,label-width=4ex]{answers}[\a]

\newcommand\gototask[1]{\addtocounter{task}{\numexpr#1-\value{task}\relax}}

\begin{document}

\begin{answers}(4)
  \a (A)
  \a (C)
  \a (D) \gototask{6}
  \a (C)
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

Both examples give

[image]

---

BTW: in your log you should be getting

```
Package tasks Warning: You've tried setting command `\NewTasks ' on line 6.
(tasks)                However, command `\NewTasks ' is deprecated. Please use
(tasks)                command `\NewTasksEnvironment ' instead. Refer to the
(tasks)                manual for details.
```

Maybe also have a look at [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc/).

Comment: It is a great solution. Thanks! It will be more convenient  if I could plug-in the required counter number instead of the number added. In your example, if somehow I could write 6 instead of 3 to go to the counter number 6, then it would be more convenient.

Comment: I don't know much LaTeX, so I could not find this elegant way to get desired result. Thanks, you solved my problem.

Comment: @prashantsharma you're welcome